# How to reference an item in an ItemGroup based on the Label attribute?

Tags: msbuild, label, itemgroup

In my cpp project file I have an item group defined as such:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="file1.dll" Label="Release Version"/>
<None Include="file2.dll" Label="Debug Version"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have an AfterBuild target whereby I want to copy the above files into different locations based on the label attribute of the item. For example:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Copy SourceFiles="@(None)" DestinationFiles="$(ReleaseLocation)" Condition="'%(None.Label)'=='Release Version'" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

However this doesn't work (nothing is copied). How do I reference the Label attribute in my Copy command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot filter items based on Label attribute, but you can filter based on item's metadata. E.g.:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="file1.dll">
   <Label>Release Version</Label>
  </None>
  <None Include="file2.dll">
    <Label>Debug Version</Label>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_RetailContent Include="@(None)" Condition="%(Label) == 'Release Version'" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_RetailContent)" DestinationFolder="$(ReleaseLocation)" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

Comment: What does 'None' stand here for?

Comment: @jayarjo, 'None' was the item group the author of the question used. There is nothing special about this group or the name of the group here, it might have been as well 'MyFavoriteItemGroup' or any other name.

Comment: The [MS doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#example) implies that Label attribute *should* be usable in "filtering" items:  *"The Label attribute is used in some build systems as a way to control build behaviors. You can use it only in declarations, as a way to create more understandable MSBuild scripts, or as a control setting to affect build actions."*